# Voice Memos with location-based naming in Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, geolocation, voice-memo

Voice Memos app in MacOS and iPhone supports a feature called "location-based naming" which sets the name of the sound recording file after the current GPS location, or some kind of geographic address detection.

However, when starting a sound recording in Apple Watch's Voice Memos app, it names it simply as a sequential identifier "Recording 5", "Recording 6", and so on...

**Is it possible somehow to apply the same naming scheme, as in MacOS's and iPhone's app, in Apple Watch?**

As far as I understand, Apple Watch also has location sensors, and of course it can also interact with linked iPhone's ones.

P.S. I'd love to know whether there are **differences in this class between models of Apple Watch** (for example, maybe in the Ultra model, this location-based naming is working well while in other models it isn't?)

P.S. 2: In case it's impossible, I'd love to hear about **possible workarounds**. Maybe we can trigger an iPhone's Shortcut/workflow from Apple Watch, that will start the Voice Memos app in iPhone, or will start another kind of sound recorder via Shortcuts - that will fulfill this naming scheme?